# tapply, plotting, length doesn't match

Tags: r, plot, tapply

I am trying to generate a plot from a dataset of 2 columns - the first column contains distances and the second contains correlations of something measured at those distances.

Now there multiple entries with the same distance but different correlation values. I want to take the average of these various entries and generate a plot of distance versus correlation. So, this is what I did (the dataset is called correlation table):

```
bins <- sort(unique(correlationtable[,1]))
corr <- tapply(correlationtable[,2],correlationtable[,1],mean)
plot(bins,corr,type = 'l')
```

However, this gives me the error that lengths of bins and corr don't match.

I cannot figure out what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it with some random data and for me it worked every time. To track the error you would need to supply us with the concrete example that did not work for you.

However to answer the question here is alternative way to do the same thing:

```
corr <- tapply(correlationtable[,2],correlationtable[,1],mean)
bins <- as.numeric(names(corr))
plot(bins,corr,type = 'l')
```

This uses the fact that tapply returns `names` attribute which then is converted into numeric and used as distance. And it must be the same length as `corr`.